# File Channel in C++

Tags: c++, c, io, filechannel

In java, there are [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)s where I can read from file channel. I can also set the position in the channel where I want to start reading.

Any similar functions in C++/C?

Comment: In the C++ world we call this a "file stream".

Comment: A channel is different than a stream. We have streams in java @Will

Comment: @user1785771: I was just trying to clarify the situation in case some people didn't know that Java has both FileInputStream and FileChannel. I added the link so that people could see what interface you wanted. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1605332/1353098

Answer (score 6):

Please look into C++'s `ifstream::seekg()` and `ifstream::tellg()`. Also in C: `ftell()` and `fseek()` functions in `<stdio.h>`

Answer (score 0):

if you want a solution with `C` programming

If you want to read from position `X` then you can use `fread()` up to the `(X-1)` and then reuse `fread()` or `fgets()` or `fgetc()` to read from the position `X`

[How to read a text file upto certain position in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252543/how-to-read-a-text-file-upto-certain-position-in-c)